# How to move a file, with the filename based on the folder name, to a subfolder in the same folder

Tags: powershell, path, filenames, move

I've been struggling for a while now, and was hoping somebody can help me out here.

I have a bunch of *.pdf files, from which the filename contains also the name of the folder the files should be moved to.
The code I found, is working well:

```
$Folder = "C:\Users\Bob\Desktop\Scripting\Bronmap"
$FileType = "*.pdf"
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder -Filter $FileType

$RE = [regex]((Get-ChildItem -Path $Folder -Directory -Name) -Join '|')
ForEach($file in $Files){
    if ($file.BaseName -Match $RE){
        $file | Move-Item -Destination (Join-Path $Folder  $Matches[0] )
    } 
    else {
        $file | Move-Item -Destination (Join-Path $Folder "No_Folder")
    }
}
```

What I would like, is that the file is moved to a subfolder in the named folder, with a certain name "Contracts". For example:

```
$file | Move-Item -Destination (Join-Path $Folder  $Matches[0] "Contracts" )
```

Although the subfolder exists, I can not get it to work.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Join-Path` takes two arguments, `$Folders` and `$Matches[0]` in your case, so `"Contracts"` shouldn't be there.

You can either use `Join-Path` twice:

```
(Join-Path (Join-Path $Folder $Matches[0]) "Contracts")
```

or concatenate Contracts manually:

```
(Join-Path $Folder ($Matches[0] + "\Contracts"))
```

Comment: Nicely done. Note that in PowerShell (Core) 7+ you now _can_ pass an open-ended number of path components to [`Join-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/join-path); e.g. `Join-Path a b c` yields `a\b\c` on Windows.

Comment: Thank you so much endo64.

`-Destination (Join-Path (Join-Path $Folder $Matches[0]) "Contracten")` worked perfect

Comment: Would it be possible to move the file to a folder ,which contains the same name as the file base name?  The script now determines a folder name, looks for that name in the files, and then moves the files to the corresponding folder. But I would like to only use the last 8 characters of the folder name.